# Transfer function of a space varying wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, wavefunction

$$\frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}-\mu \epsilon \frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}-\mu \sigma \frac{\partial  \psi}{\partial t}=0$$

Is the wave electromagnetic wave equation in lossy, source free, homogeneous medium. If I had a boundary value problem $\psi (x=x_0,t)=f(t)$ (forward travelling) I could find what would happen at any point in space using the transfer function.

$$\int F(\omega)e^{i \gamma(\omega) (x-x_0) }d\omega$$
where $\gamma(\omega)$ is the complex propagation constant

What if the wave equation was something like

$$\frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}-\mu \epsilon (x) \frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}-\mu \sigma \frac{\partial  \psi}{\partial t}=0$$

or even

$$\frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}-\mu \epsilon (x) \frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}=0$$

more simply.

I want to find its transfer function, not other methods of solving.

Comment: In physics that's called the Green's function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function, but it's not considered as a good way of solving the kind of problem you are looking at, hence the century long research on all those "other" methods that you don't want (for whatever reason).

Comment: I am curious about this method. I guess I can find the green's function for solving the equation with a delta function on the rhs and then take convolve/multiply in fourier domain. Is it possible to take $x$'s fourier transform and find it in fourier domain? Of course I would end up with a convolution integral in the expression and not be able to evaluate it but maybe there is a way?

Comment: also i'd like to hear what those other methods are. (are those just normal ways of solving a differential equation/numerical?)

Comment: The last time I took numerical mathematics II (partial differential equations) was 30+ years ago and the only thing I remember is that there are serious convergence problems of the sort of the Gibbs phenomenon (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GibbsPhenomenon.html) if one attempts to approximate with a dumb old Fourier transform. If you are serious about solving real world problems of this kind you are well advised to get a textbook on the subject, which is far from trivial.

Comment: When I said numerical, I did not mean numerically evaluating fourier transorms. I was asking what other better ways there are. I do not claim this is a good way of solving such problems, I am curious how it could be done.

Comment: Hence "see a century of research summarized in a modern textbook". Seriously, you are asking for a simple solution that doesn't exist. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25614/discussion-between-grdgfgr-and-curiousone).

Comment: I am asking for a name.